# How to give particles a physics material or make them have no friction?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, physics-engine

I have particle emitter with a y force of -9.8, so they fall down like sand. Unfortunately, when they hit a plank (a cube with an ice physics material on its box collider) that is slanted at a 45 degree angle, they slide very slowly down it.

Can you give particles a physics material like ice? If not, how to reduce the friction between particles and all other objects so it flows downward more quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the Static and Dynamic friction of the material you are using, and set friction combine to minimum.

If this doesn't work, try using negative values of Friction Direction 2 amd then apply Fynamic Friction 2 and Static Friction 2 (but i don't think you'll need to go this far, reducing friction should work fine).

[unity3D Physic material reference](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-PhysicMaterial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but how do I apply a physics material to the particles? I can give the object that's emitting the particles a physics material but I don't see any way to give the particles themselves a physics material. In the particle renderer there is a "material" I can set but I think it's just visual because I can't put any of my "physics materials" in for it.

Comment: Don't apply physic material to the particles, apply it to the surface you want them to slide on. Try different settings for the parameters i have described and you should be able to find the values that give the effect you want to create.

Comment: Since you have already applied ice Physic material, double click on it to reveal its properties and change the settings for the parameters i have mentioned in the reply. this should work.

Comment: It seems that no matter what I change the physics of the ramp to, the particles just inch their way down bit by bit. It's not even a smooth slide. When I drop a cube object on the same ramp, it slides down nicely. I must be missing something?

Comment: Well now i am confused as well, it shouldn't behave like this! Let me find an answer and i'll be sure to post here.

Answer (score -1):

We did not apply the physic material on partical system .Because there is no option for using the physic material